# VBA string concatenation doesn't work if I use wildcard "*"

Tags: excel, vba

This little piece of code **concatenates a couple of cell values creates a string** that is then searched for in a VB array. If I don't use **"*"** in concatenation it works, if I do it breaks the block below.

Any ideas?

**Code that works:**

```
For i = 1 To StringsCount
  arrStrings(i, 1) = .Range("A" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("D" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("E" & i + k).Value
  arrStrings(i, 2) = .Range("A" & i + k).Row                      
  k = k + 11
Next i
```

**Code that doesn't work:**

```
For i = 1 To StringsCount
  arrStrings(i, 1) = .Range("A" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("D" & i + k).Value & "_" & .Range("E" & i + k).Value & "*"
  arrStrings(i, 2) = .Range("A" & i + k).Row
  k = k + 11
Next i
```

*(Second row, at the far end, there is additional wildcard char. '&"*"' ).*

**Block that "doesn't work"breaks this one below (the quoted line):**

```
interSum = 0

For i = 1 To UBound(arrStrings)
  For j = LBound(arrCampaignsAmounts, 1) To UBound(arrCampaignsAmounts, 1)
    If arrStrings(i, 1) = arrCampaignsAmounts(j, 1) Then
      interSum = interSum + arrCampaignsAmounts(j, 2)  
    End If
   Next j
```

> SourceSheet.Range("H" & arrStrings(i, 2)).Value = interSum

```
    interSum = 0
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried `If arrCampaignsAmounts(j, 1) LIKE arrStrings(i, 1) Then` with the wildcard?

Comment: Even with LIKE, still all zeroes :(.

Comment: Well, I would use the [Array Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fat7fw0s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method with one-dimensioned arrays but there is no data to test any possible solution on. Anything I come up with is very unlikely to be remotely close to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you possibly avoid the wildcard and use `InStr` instead? So, rather than

```
If arrStrings(i, 1) = arrCampaignsAmounts(j, 1) Then
```

you'd have

```
If InStr(arrCampaignsAmounts(j, 1),arrStrings(i, 1)) > 0 Then
```

with your initial no-wildcard string formation. This should work, as `InStr` will return a 0 if it finds no match.
Similarly, if you wanted your `arrStrings` value to always be the start of the string you're matching against, you could use `=1` rather than `>0`.

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, a string "Belgium_gdn_january_np" from arrStrings will be found within arrCampaignsAmounts in "Belgium_gdn_january_np_(FL)" string and its corresponding value added to amount interSum?

Comment: Yes - `InStr` will return 1 because it will find the string "Belgium_gdn_january_np" at position 1 of "Belgium_gdn_january_np_(FL)"